# Auto login JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been logging into a website for points.  I've gotten pretty lazy and don't want to enter the account information myself.  I tried writing a script to enter the information for me.
So I went to the log-in page, right clicked, inspected elements, and found the input tags' ids for the email and password input areas.  Then I tried accessing and changing their values through the DOM.

Below is my attempt at modifying the value of the input tag with id "email"

```
myWindow = window.open(url);
var em = myWindow.document.getElementById("email");
alert(em==null);
em.value.replace("email");
```

The alert is my way of testing if the input tag was received.  It prints out true and I don't know why because I look back at the page and it does exist.  The tag with the id "email" is right there.  Could this be because of the website's security somehow?

Comment: *"I tried writing a script to enter the information for me"* - you mean, a bot?

Comment: You do realize that if it is part of the website's security, you are asking SO users to help _defeat_ said security.

Comment: Is the DOM loaded at this point in time?  It could be a race condition.  Try using a `setTimeout` to push it out by a few seconds.

Comment: Maybe try autohotkey for something like this instead.  I use ahk scripts to log in to some of my games and collect stuff when I'm not at home.

Comment: Crackertastic: That is a good point...I think I'll just log in on my own.

Comment: DontVoteMeDown: I guess?

Comment: Howard Renollet: thanks, but Crackertastic has me to paranoid to continue LOL